# React, Node js Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint '<URL>'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

У меня есть сервер на котором находится фронтенд(React) и бэкенд(Node js), работающие на разных портах. Все было хорошо, до того момента пока для пока для фронтенда не поставил ssl сертфикат и теперь он работает на https, бэкенд - http. Проблема заключается в том что фронтенд(использую axios для реквестов) и бэкенд не хотят друг с другом общаться.

Сообщение об ошибке: `Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Прошу, помогите.

Comment: Поставь на бекенде ssl-сертификат и ходи по https

Comment: а axios сможет к https обращаться?

Comment: А что бы ему не смочь?

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо вам большое